# Displaying algorithm run time in python

Tags: python

I am required to display the time it took to run two different algorithms using functions available in the time library.  I'm assuming I have to use the timeit() function however I'm not familiar as to how to incorporate that into the code.  So far this is what I have:

```
import time
def time2Algorithms(sound):

  # normalize(sound)

  largest = 0
  for s in getSamples(sound):
    largest = max(largest,getSampleValue(s) )
  multiplier = 32767.0 / largest
  for s in getSamples(sound):
    louder = multiplier * getSampleValue(s)
    setSampleValue(s,louder)
  explore(sound)

  # onlyMaximize(sound)

  for sample in getSamples(sound):
      value = getSampleValue(sample)
      if value >= 0:
        setSampleValue(sample,32767)
      if value < 0:
        setSampleValue(sample,-32768)
  explore(sound)
```

My goal is to display the run times of both the normalize and maximize algorithms after they execute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` module (which you are required to use) does not include `timeit` (different module).

Just add a

```
start = time.time()
```

just before the part you want to time, and e.g

```
print(time.time() - start)
```

just after said part -- this will display the elapsed time in seconds.  Ornament and format that as required, of course:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeit like this

```
import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
# Your algo goes here
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
```

and also time module which is easy

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
# Your algo goes here
elapsed = time.time() - start_time
```